# Can Azure Data Lake store .dbf (Oracle), .accdb (MS Access) or .mdf (SQL Server) files?

Tags: azure, etl, azure-data-lake, azure-data-lake-gen2

Just trying to wrap my head around this as I was doing a lot of reading and there's a lot of confusing marketing information out there.

So my company lives in a world of relational databases including Oracle, MS Access and MS SQL Server.

We were wanting to consolidate data sources into a data lake, in particular Azure Data Lake which is marketed as being able to store any sort of data, but upon further reading it seems that it can only store data in a few file formats including parquet, CSV etc.

So my question is - If we have a bunch of relational databases, do we need to

1. Access the source database via an ETL tool (for example Azure Data Factory)
2. Grab the source tables of interest and pull it into ADF
3. Convert and finally output the data into one of the Azure Data Lake file formats (csv, parquet etc) using ADL as a target

Did I get this right? For some reason I naively thought you could just grab the data files and drop it into the data lake. I just wanted to make sure that there is a step needed to "convert" the source table(s) and output it into a more common file format (csv, parquet etc).

Answer (score 1):

> I just wanted to make sure that there is a step needed to "convert"
> the source table(s) and output it into a more common file format (csv,
> parquet etc).

Azure Data Factory supports only below formats as Source.

[image]

You can connect select tables from Oracle, MS Access and SQL Server as Source. But, you can not select .dbf, .accdb and .mdf file formats as source in ADF.

ADLS supported file formats are given in this [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-best-practices#file-formats)

Refer - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/supported-file-formats-and-compression-codecs

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the source file formats for ADF, that answers one half of my question. For ADLS based on the provided link it mentions a few file formats (JSON, CSV) and a few other ones like ORC and Parquet, but I didnt see a list of supported file formats for storage? I am just curious if someone wanted to just take the .dbf file from an Oracle database and drop it into an Azure Data Lake, would that be possible?